# Drop a row depending on the content of the row after it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   A B C
0  1 0 0
1  1 1 1
2  1 0 0
3  1 0 0
4  1 1 1
5  1 0 0
```

How do I remove a row based on the contents of the row after it? I only want to keep the rows where the row below is 1 1 1 and remove anything where it is 1 0 0 or doesnt exist. So in this case row 2 and 5 would be dropped.

Comment: Why isn't 2 dropped? Doesn't 1 0 0 come after it?

Comment: my mistake, i made the correction, 2 and 5 should be dropped

Comment: your `1 1 1` doesn't have a `1 1 1` below it, you didn't say you want to keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `shift` with `eq` and `all`

```
df[(df.eq(1).all(1))|(df.eq(1).all(1).shift(-1))]
Out[228]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  1  1  1
3  1  0  0
4  1  1  1
```

Update

```
s=df.astype(str).apply(','.join,1)
df[(s=='1,1,1')|((s=='1,1,1').shift(-1))|(s!='1,0,0')]
Out[237]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  1  1  1
3  1  0  0
4  1  1  1
```

Comment: Lol, interesting hack!

Answer (score 0):

To get rows that meet your requirements you can use:

```
df[df.shift(-1).apply(tuple, axis=1)==(1,1,1)]
#   A  B  C
#0  1  0  0
#3  1  0  0
```

Or this one to get rows 2 and 5:

```
df[df.shift(1).apply(tuple, axis=1)==(1,1,1)]
#   A  B  C
#2  1  0  0
#5  1  0  0
```

Or if 2 and 5 get dropped this will make it happen:

```
df[(df.shift(-1).apply(tuple, axis=1)==(1,1,1))|(df.apply(tuple, axis=1)==(1,1,1))]
#   A  B  C
#0  1  0  0
#1  1  1  1
#3  1  0  0
#4  1  1  1
```